# Anime movie about giant robot head that crashes

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm trying to figure out the name an old anime movie I watched as a child, most likely late 80s - early 90s. It featured a giant robot, which consisted of separate parts with a pilot in each, and they combined to form the complete robot. It sounds kinda like Voltron but I'm pretty sure it wasn't, maybe a knock-off or something. The head had horns, which seemed to go out horizontally from the base and then turned upwards, or there was a wide base and the horns went up on either side of the head.

I seem to remember the parts being launched from a base and I think the plot involved the head crashing or otherwise being separated from the body. I haven't even thought about this movie for a very long time so I may be remembering some details wrong, but if anything else comes to me I'll edit it in.

Comment: This sounds a lot like the conceit of the *"Metal Hourlant"* of the *Heavy Metal* live action series on SyFy -- except that was after 2010s, live action, and the head was from a metal planet, not a robot...

Comment: sounds like you are describing the head of Galactus but I doubt there was ever an iteration where what you are remembering happened with that character.

Answer (score 3):

The anime I was looking for seems to be Force Five: Gaiking (although it seems to have other names).

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaiking):

> A mecha defender robot consisting of three separate components: the
> Great Space Dragon's head, an arm unit, and a leg unit (the arm and
> leg units are stored inside the Great Space Dragon and exit from a
> gateway located below the Dragon's head). These three launch from the
> Great Space Dragon and combine, while in flight, to form Gaiking. The
> Great Space Dragon's head forms Gaiking's core (i.e., chest and back)
> and contains Gaiking's own head. Gaiking is operated by baseball star
> Sanshiro Tsuwabuki ("Aries Astonopolous" in English and "Brando
> Drummond" in Spanish).

Now that I read that description I remember the baseball star being featured prominently, with one scene in particular showing him pitching balls that disappear.

[image: Gaiking]

In the picture above you can see the distinctive horns.